# Power BI Report Builder - Multiple reports using same template and only replacing fields

Tags: sql, parameters, report, builder, multivalue

The current project consists of producing multiple reports (e.g., report cards), but paginating them through the report builder.

The objective is to create multiple reports by selecting people's names via a parameter which filter the database into a small table and having the values in a given row populate the report builder fields.

The problem is that I am selecting multiple names in the parameter (i.e., multi-value parameter), but only one report with **the first row is produced**. I believe the issue is that the fields that populate for the report only record the first row of the tables created via the parameter filtration (field expression is '=first(value)')

Any help is appreciated. I mostly need a direction. I believe the issue is that the report builder is only building off the first row of the table and I need a way for the builder to 'loop' through the table and produce a report for each row.

Basic idea is creating multiple report cards for students and these reports are curated by the parameter value (student name) which can select multiple names.